# Mfcuk tool not working properly

Tags: elementaryos, brute-force, nfc

I recently managed to install libnfc. I wanted to test the tools *mfoc* and *mfcuk*, designed to obtain the keys of a NFC tag. Mfoc can retrieve all the keys only if it knows at least one key, Mfcuk can brute-force the tag to obtain any keys.

I am using a NFC tag bought from eBay. And a PN532 breakout board from epalsite.com (A cheap version). There have been no problems using nfc-list, nor [mfoc (output)](https://gist.github.com/VarhdVohrs/feaa563ba9c6ff39dff562f0d7f6ea98). However, on the attempt to use mfcuk with the tag I [haven't had success (output)](https://gist.github.com/VarhdVohrs/49430508079e2e8c2ca63f53a237c24e).

First I noticed the key doesn't change at all. It remains 000000000000. I supposed that was not an error. Then I waited for almost an hour with no success. I assumed that being a tag with default keys would mean that it would be solved in very short time. I later tried using mfcuk to obtain only the A key of one block, but also not successfully.

Is it an error on my configuration or hardware, or is it just not enough time has elapsed? What other debug log can I analyze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked. I used a Kali Linux live USB, I issued the command

> mfcuk -C -O mifare-02.dmp -R 0:A -s 250 -S 250 -v 3

Then I used

> mfoc -k THISISTHEKEYIGOT -O across01.mfd

It is worth mentioning root is the default user in Kali Linux
It made approximately 1000 Auths before the correct key.
The "Key: 000000..." is actually normal, your best shot is to try to get only one key and be patient.

Comment: I let turn mfcuk during 3 hours around and it still continue without gave me any key. How many times could be token ?